# Saml Implementation Using NodeJS/Passport

Tags: node.js, saml-2.0

I want to implement saml using passport module of node js using my own idp. But the below links that i found are using some openidp/adfs/shibboleth etc.

```
https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml

https://github.com/lmarkus/passport-saml-encrypted

https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2js
```

I have created two localhost apps ,one functioning as sp(service provider) ,other as idp(identity provider) and while redirecting from sp to idp i am sending the encrypted saml and than i am validating the user using passport ldap module,but i need to know that whether the certificates/public/private key needs to be present at idp side also ? How will idp send back the response and in what format ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are signing the AuthnRequest or encrypting the token then the IDP needs the public keys.

The SP needs the IDP token signing public key.

The IDP will send back an AuthnResponse which contains the SAML token which contains the assertions (claims).

The easiest way to see this is to use the Fiefox SAML tracer add-on.